# register inferred by blocking assignment and races

Tags: verilog

I am new to verilog and have a doubt concerning the race conditions in the following code which is taken from FPGA Prototyping by Veriloog Examples by Pong P. Chu. The code is:

```
always @(posedge clk)
a = b;
always @(posedge clk)
b = a;
```

This will infer races depending on which always block gets executed first. But always blocks should get executed in parallel. Correct me if I am wrong. I know there is blocking assignment but how does it affect the first statement of the block, which is the always statement? 
The second code using the non-blocking assignment is:-

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin //b(entry) = b
a <= b; //a(exit) = b(entry)
end //a = a(exit)

always @(posedge clk)
begin //a(entry) = a
b <= a; //b(exit) = a(entry)
end //b = b(exit)
```

This will work fine according to the book but I couldn't understand why? Is it because the always blocks are executed in parallel in this case because of non-blocking assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Because the Verilog "stratified event queue" has different regions, the type of assignment operator used makes a difference in how the code is executed. The details can be found in section 5 of the IEEE Verilog standard, but in terms of your question, it boils roughly down to this:

- The blocking assignments (in your first example) are evaluated immediately, i.e. when the `always` block they're in is activated. Since both blocks are parallel, order of their activation is undefined.
- The non-blocking assignments are not executed immediately but rather *scheduled* after all blocks of the same time step have finished executing.

So when encountering a rising `clk` edge, in your first example a simulator would

1. Pick at random one of the `always` blocks
2. Find that the assignment is a blocking one and execute it immediately, therefore changing the left-hand variable in that assignment.
3. Pick the other `always` block and do the same, at which point the value of the first variable was already changed.

In your second example, the simulator would

1. Pick at random one of the `always` blocks
2. Find that the assignment is a non-blocking one and therefore
3. evaluate the right-hand side of the `=` sign and schedule the value it found there as a non-blocking assign update event to the variable left of the `=`.
4. Pick the other `always` block and do the same. Note that both variables still have their values from before the rising `clk` edge.
5. Since all blocks are done executing, update all variables which were scheduled for non-blocking assign update events, effectively swapping their values.