# How do I add 1 to a 4 bit wire in Verilog

Tags: verilog

This seems like it would be simple, but I can't find out how to do this anywhere... All I want to do is add 1 to a 4 bit wire.

Overall, I want to count the number of 1's in a 8 bit variable. Let's call this input inA. The output will be outA. Both are defined as wires; inA is 8 bits where outA is 4 bits.

```
wire[0:7] inA;
wire[0:3] outA;
```

I can do a for loop to go through the array:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 7; i = i + 1) begin
    if (inA[i] == 1) begin
       outA <= outA + 1;
    end
end
```

But this isn't working. 
Can someone please help? I am extremely new to Verilog (and VHDL), so I really have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, here is one option:

```
  reg [0:3] ones;
  integer i;
  always @ (inA) begin
    ones = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin
      ones = ones + inA[i];
    end
  end
  assign outA = ones;
```

Since you haven't provided your full source code (e.g. the context of the `for` loop), we can only guess what the problem with that is.

Remember though that non-blocking assignments like `outA <= outA + 1` will be *scheduled to be executed at the end of the `always` block*, such that the last assignment will *override* all previous ones.

Since `outA` (which by the way will have to be a `reg` if your `for` loop is embedded in an `always` block), is only updated after the `always` block has finished "executing", only `inA[7]` can cause an increment to `outA`.

Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369333/897968) for further information on how `always` blocks are executed.

Comment: This was perfect, thanks! I am assuming the addition of ones and then assigning the output the value of ones was what I was missing.

Thank you, again!

Comment: @Apolymoxic why do you need the value as a `wire`?

Comment: @Morgan I don't think it was absolutely needed... it was simply where I started. It was supposed to mimic an output, and in a real functioning hardware program, wouldn't it be a wire?

Comment: Nope, reg vs wire is language syntax nothing to do with hardware, reg does not imply a flip flop register.